# Extra Wordpress Theme - Mobile menu at certain resolution

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile

I'm using a Extra Wordpress Theme and I want that the menu go to mobile menu at certain resolution. So I found a Divi code
    @media only screen and max-width: 1243px and min-width: 980px { #top-menu-nav { display:none; }} @media only screen and max-width: 1243px and min-width: 980px { #et_mobile_nav_menu { display:block }}
But #top-menu-nav don't exist on Extra theme, I already search on Extra Style CSS but I can't find the right one.

Answer (score 1):

In Extra Wordpress Theme, top menu is inside 'et-navigation' css id. So instead of using  #top-menu-na, use #et-navigation and apply the media only screen codes.

Comment: First, thank you very much. We have progress but it didn't work. The menu disappear but didn't appear the mobile menu. [Code](http://www.codesend.com/view/5fe36c81d3bd1b91bbe13e91fff89e87/)